# Limitations of sharpDevelop

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, sharpdevelop

I am looking in to using sharpDevelop to develop Windows (.NET) applications over using Visual Studio.  I'm just wondering if there are any serious limitations to using SharpDevelop over VS?  The price is certainly right and at first glance it seems like a pretty decent IDE.  I'm just wondering if it is compatible with VS.  I mean if I am collaborating with other developers that are using VS, can we seamlessly pass projects/solutions back and forth and work on them? Just wondering what people's opinions are.

Comment: You can get the free Express ediotion of VS2010 to try too http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Comment: THe express editions are very limiting, for example there is no way to opena solution that contains a web app and a class library in one IDE using the express editions.  A web app and class library is the foundation of almost everything i develop so i find them next to useless.

Answer (score 3):

Past year I start using SharpDevelop to develop a large application.

Based on my experience, I can say these are some advantages in using it:

1. It's faster than Visual Studio; if your project is pretty large, you have to spend less time waiting for the project to compile
2. It's free

One important disadvantage I've found is the lack of a good refactoring system, in Visual Studio I used Jetbrains Resharper for its great refactoring support.

Now I've returned to use Visual Studio, just for the facilities offered by Resharper.

Answer (score 3):

SharpDevelop 4.0 Beta 4 (as the most current version) is pretty stable as for a Beta. Besides being free it has some pretty features which can be extended via AddIn (a sort of plugin system). A large number of project templates for the most popular languages supporting the .NET Framework. A possible limitation is the support for ASP.NET which still lags behind VS.

Surely you can bet that the top versions of Visual Studio may have some better tools, options, better integration and so on. 
Please consider comparing SharpDevelop to the Express Editions of VS. Then it will be obvious that SD is a big win if you don't have to pay. Consider it also as a different product, not only a copy of VS (just not to say 'option X is called here Y, opposed to VS').

Answer (score 3):

This feature by feature comparison [list](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/articles/VisualStudioExpressComparison.aspx) for SharpDevelop vs. VS Express might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project that was started using Visual Studio 2010. Although according to a special engine we've created the number of code lines is not very high, the project builds very slowly. I tested sharpdevelop, and it was about an order of magnitude faster!! The only problem we faced was that we could not debug our server and client together, something that VS does like a charm (well, that charm requires some patience), and shows the stack trace of the server, on top of the client, which is very useful.

My suggestion: use sharpdevelop unless you absolutely need a feature it lacks.

Answer (score 0):

SharpDevelop 4.0 Beta does not support the default Visual Studio installer projects. However, since these are going to be deprecated after VS2010 by Microsoft, this is probably not a main issue for you.